# Optimisation of large matrix calculation

Tags: python, optimization

I need to calculate a distance matrix on a large dataset (about 20k samples)

```
distance_matrix = np.ndarray((len(foo),len(foo)))
for i, bar1 in enumerate(foo):
    for j, bar2 in enumerate(foo[i+1:]):
        distance_matrix[i,j] = hight_level_python_function(bar1, bar2)
```

Which optimisation techniques can be used to decrease a calculation time besides slicing marix and passing each to different processs?

- I can't port this code to low-level languages
- I can't use pypy

UPD: My array contains strings, so I'cant use ufuncs or `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`.

Comment: Since you are using numpy, you probably want to write  hight_level_python_function in terms of ufuncs. This would allow numpy to vectorize the whole thing. This will let you remove both loops and just say 
`distance_matrix[i,j] = hight_level_python_function(arange(len(foo),arange(len(foo))`

Comment: Will there be duplicate calls to `hight_level_python_function`?  That is, where the same `bar1` and `bar2` will occur more than once?  Or, where they are swapped and the same result is returned?  If so, you could cache those....

Comment: Cache is already used.

Comment: @OscarSmith great idea.

Comment: ufuncs are one of those magical things that makes your code way faster. They are almost always the right answer when you are working with numpy.

Comment: @OscarSmith, sounds like you have a winner there.  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: What strings are in your array/ what do foo and bar look like?

Comment: @OscarSmith, <U96 dtype